# Value of a definite integral changes when rearranging the integrand.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Consider $I=\int^{2\pi}_0\sqrt{1-\sin\phi}~\mathrm d\phi.$ A quick calculator check shows that the value of this integral is about $5.7$.

If we now try to get the integrand into a form that can be integrated:

\begin{align*}
I&=\int^{2\pi}_0\sqrt{1-\sin\phi}\ \frac{\sqrt{1+\sin\phi}}{\sqrt{1+\sin\phi}}\mathrm d\phi\\
&=\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{\cos\phi}{\sqrt{1+\sin\phi}}\mathrm d\phi\\
&= 2\sqrt{1+\sin\phi} \ |^{2\pi}_0 = 0
\end{align*}

There is clearly something wrong here, because we know already that $I=5.7$, and yet the algebra all checks out. I can only assume that the use of $\frac{\sqrt{1+\sin\phi}}{\sqrt{1+\sin\phi}}$ is invalid somehow. Is this the case, and if so then why?

Comment: $$\sqrt{\cos^2(\phi)}=\left|\cos(\phi)\right|$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integral is - because of $\sqrt{\cos^2x} = |\cos x|$ - rather

$$\int^{2\pi}_0\sqrt{1-\sin\phi}~\mathrm d\phi = \int^{\pi/2}_0\frac{\cos\phi}{\sqrt{1+\sin\phi}}\mathrm d\phi - \int^{3\pi/2}_{\pi/2}\frac{\cos\phi}{\sqrt{1+\sin\phi}}\mathrm d\phi + \int^{2\pi}_{3\pi/2}\frac{\cos\phi}{\sqrt{1+\sin\phi}}\mathrm d\phi$$ $$= 2(\sqrt{2}-1) + 2\sqrt{2} + 2 = 4\sqrt{2}$$